# What is the naming convention for interfaces and classes in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have the following:

```
interface IUser {
  email: string
  password: string
}

class User {
  email: string
  password: string
  constructor(email: string, password: string) {
    this.email = email
    this.password = password
  }

  isEmailValid(): boolean {
    return validatorJs.isEmail(this.email)
  }

  isPasswordValid(): boolean {
    return validatorJs.isStrongPassword(this.password, opts)
  }
}

function createUser(user: IUser) {
  // applying isPasswordValid and isEmailValid
  //insert ...
}

function getUser(): IUser {
  return new User('foo@bar.com', 'foobar')
}
```

I have to put the letter "I" before the interface name, is that correct or should I do it differently?

Comment: CamelCased without `I`

Comment: There used to be [a linter rule for this](https://github.com/bradzacher/eslint-plugin-typescript/blob/master/docs/rules/interface-name-prefix.md), with the default value being not having a prefix. In my very subjective opinion, no prefix is considerably more common in the Typescript community, but naturally there are those who look the other way too.

Comment: If it's in the same file then use `IUser` if you plan to use the interface on its own otherwise if both interface and class are named `User` then the class will be merged with the interface.

Comment: @Etheryte In my experience no `I` is also pretty common. However, I think at least C# developers tend to use the `I` as it's the convention in that language. It *does* also make some sense as a [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) to mark what's an implementation and what isn't. But you can also definitely go the other way and say that it doesn't matter. Which conforms with [the Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) (the **L** in SO**L**id). So, it's down to preference.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Someone has developed a TypeScript style guide. You can find it here: https://ts.dev/style

From that guide:

> This is the style guide for the TypeScript language that was based on the one that is provided by Google. It contains both rules and best practices. Choose those that work best for your team.

This is what it says about interface naming:

> Do not mark interfaces specially ( <strike>IMyInterface</strike> or <strike>MyFooInterface</strike>)
> unless it's idiomatic in its environment. When introducing an
> interface for a class, give it a name that expresses why the interface
> exists in the first place (e.g. class TodoItem and interface
> TodoItemStorage if the interface expresses the format used for
> storage/serialization in JSON).

Answer (score 18):

There's no official naming convention though it's common in the broader TS community to *not* use `I` for interfaces unless they're explicitly for being implemented by classes like:

```
import type { IUser } from '$models/interfaces/iuser.interface';
import type { IDeserializable } from '$models/interfaces/ideserializable.interface';

export class UserModel implements IDeserializable<IUser>, IUser {
  public email: string;
  public password: string;

  deserialize(input: IUser): this {
    Object.assign(this, input);
    return this;
  }
}
```

(Pattern adapted from [sveltekit-starter](https://github.com/navneetsharmaui/sveltekit-starter) by Navneet Sharma.)

So which naming method you choose for interfaces is ultimately at your own discretion.

Comment: Let's say that I have the case of returning a User in a function (User interface) but for that I need to create an instance of the User class, how would I distinguish them? should I name the class UserDTO or something like that?

Comment: @DiegoLopeLoyola do you *need* to distinguish them?  If your interface must only be fulfilled by a specific class, then I don't see the value of the interface.

Comment: I understand that to specify the return type I have to use an interface. In the example that I mentioned, I need a User class that implements the same fields of the User interface, and also that same class has methods that validate the user and some of its fields, that is why I came up with naming the interface IUser

Comment: @VLAZ what do you mean? interface may have 2+ implementations: User and MyUser. Both maybe returned as IUser. Even if stupid not-OOP language like JavaScript doesn't support it, it's a common approach for all programming language and called polymorphism.

Comment: @ArtemA the context wasn't polymorphism. OP clearly stated that they want the return value to be an interface but they want a very specific implementation of that interface to be returned. Which isn't polymorphic and goes against Liskov substitution principle - the **L** in SO**L**ID. And the whole approach is [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) because OP talked about differentiating implementation and interface based on *name*. The name is completely irrelevant - the contract is.

Comment: @ArtemA  And since OP wants the contract the class exposes, there is no need to differentiate *by name* at all. A proper way to handle this is to have the contract you want as an interface and work with that. With that said, TS classes are *also* interfaces. So you *can* have a different implementation of the `User` even if that's a class.

Comment: Can you please clarify when do you create an interface that is not to meant to be explicitly implemented by classes? Looks like the vast majority of interfaces are to be implemented by classes, no?

Comment: That's the thing though. how are we supposed to distinguish between classes and interfaces if not all Interfaces are supposed to have "I" prefix. like class Car and interface Car for car properties. isn't there supposed to be a difference?

Comment: @VLAZ-onstrike- is JS your only language? Interface is a declaration a metadata. Interfaces should always have the implementation, so they alsways have to have a class: ICar -> Car. there can be a syntax sugar like "you don't need a separate class to implement ICar because the properties are the same" but it's only the sugar.
And nobody say that contract is not relevant. Yes, name can be different, but it just confuses, that's why they add I to the name of the interface for most cases.

Answer (score 0):

The answers are opinionated for this. Microsoft's convention [here](https://makecode.com/extensions/naming-conventions#:%7E:text=TypeScript%20conventions&text=Names%20are%20%E2%80%9Ccontracted%E2%80%9D%20meaning%20the,methods%2C%20fields%20are%20camel%20cased.)
But following is the general norm:

1. Classes are generally noun, written in PascalCase
2. Interface is also PascalCase (prefixing 'I' is not recommended)
3. Enums and it's fields are both written in PascalCase
4. variables (let/const) are written in camelCase. Sometimes `const` are also written in `UPPERCASE`.