# TypeError: data.map is not a function yet data is an array

Tags: reactjs, axios

I get this error

**TypeError: data.map is not a function**

from the following code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

// Import shadcn-ui components
import {
Table,
TableBody,
TableCaption,
TableCell,
TableHead,
TableHeader,
TableRow,
} from "@/components/ui/table";

// Define the expected data structure for a service

interface firmServices {
\_id: string;
service_category: string;
service_name: string;
criticality: string;
service_type: string;
}

const ServicesList = () =\> {
// State to hold the retrieved services as an array
const initialState: firmServices\[\] = \[\];
const \[data, setData\] = useState(initialState);

useEffect(() =\> {
const fetchData = async () =\> {
try {
const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:3500/services");
const servicesData: firmServices\[\] = response.data;

        setData(servicesData);
        console.log(servicesData);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error getting data", error);
        // You might want to set an error state or display an error message to the user
      }
    };
    
    fetchData();

}, \[\]);

return (
\<Table\>
\<TableCaption\>Firm Services\</TableCaption\>
\<TableHeader\>
\<TableRow\>
\<TableHead className="text-left"\>Name\</TableHead\>
\<TableHead className="text-left"\>Criticality\</TableHead\>
\<TableHead className="text-left"\>Type\</TableHead\>
\<TableHead className="text-left"\>Group\</TableHead\>
\</TableRow\>
\</TableHeader\>
\<TableBody\>
{data.map((servicesData) =\> (
\<TableRow key={servicesData.\_id}\>
\<TableCell\>{servicesData.service_category}\</TableCell\>
\<TableCell\>{servicesData.service_name}\</TableCell\>
\<TableCell\>{servicesData.criticality}\</TableCell\>
\<TableCell\>{servicesData.service_type}\</TableCell\>
\</TableRow\>
))}
\</TableBody\>
\</Table\>
);
};

export default ServicesList;
```

however the data is an array as follows from the console.log:

> ```
> {firmServices: Array(6)}firmServices:Array(6)0:{_id: '6545d10db1f1c084db6134ea', service_category: 'Deposites', service_name: 'saving', criticality: 'high', service_type: 'client, internal'}1:{_id: '6545d10db1f1c084db6134eb', service_category: 'Deposites', service_name: 'checking', criticality: 'high', service_type: 'client, internal'}2:{_id: '6545d10db1f1c084db6134ec', service_category: 'Deposites', service_name: 'saving', criticality: 'high', service_type: 'client, internal'}3:{_id: '6545d10db1f1c084db6134ed', service_category: 'Deposites', service_name: 'saving', criticality: 'high', service_type: 'client, internal'}4:{_id: '6545d10db1f1c084db6134ee', service_category: 'Deposites', service_name: 'saving', criticality: 'high', service_type: 'client, internal'}5:{_id: '6545d10db1f1c084db6134ef', service_category: 'Deposites', service_name: 'saving', criticality: 'high', service_type: 'client, internal'}length:6
> ```
>
> I have read all the issues posted that I can find most of which point to map.data needing an array, yet the data I have is an array.

Anyone shed any light on this for me.

Thanks in advance

I was expecting a table to be rendered using Table from shadcn-ui

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you have not made the state initialization properly.

```
const [data, setData] = useState<firmServices[]>(initialState);
```

When making interfaces use a naming naming convention like preceding an `I`

```
interface IfirmServices {
  _id: string; 
  service_category: string;
  service_name: string;
  criticality: string;
  service_type: string; 
}
```

```
const initialState: IfirmServices[] = [];
const [data, setData] = useState<IfirmServices[]>(initialState);
```

For your reference:

[how to set react typescript useState fetch type and using map method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61158600/how-to-set-react-typescript-usestate-fetch-type-and-using-map-method)

[What is the naming convention for interfaces and classes in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68503504/what-is-the-naming-convention-for-interfaces-and-classes-in-typescript)

Comment: Thanks....but I get the same response. Interestingly I have another identical component (CountryLists.tsx) that does exactly the same thing which does work. I added your proposed changes to this also and it worked but not with the ServicesList.tsx.  So, I'm still stumped

Comment: I fixed it. It was an error with the backend.  In my response I had res.json({firmServices}); instead of res.json(firmServices);